# How to set the editor window tab width in eclipse? (not whitespaces)

Tags: eclipse, installation

I wondered if it's possible to set the editor windows tab width in eclipse.

I hate it when I want to close several windows in a row and I always have to move the mouse. Can I set eclipse to use only ONE width for every window tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do that. Why not use the keyboard shortcut instead?

You didn't specify platform, but on Windows the shortcut is Ctrl-W. That way, you don't have to move your mouse.

Comment: It's the same shortcut on linux.

I always use keyboard commands, only if I'm browsing around the millions of views and windows, I use the mouse because STRG+PgUp/Dwn isn't very useful with lots of windows.

Comment: The key binding has nothing to do with MS-Windows, rather it is Default vs. Emacs key bindings.